# Implementing Python pyquaternion.rotation_matrix function in DirectX

Tags: python, c++, directx

I converting code by former programmers written in Python to DirectX and I'm having some trouble getting the angle orientation correctly.

The python library they are using to import and compose rotation matrices is `pyquaternion` https://github.com/KieranWynn/pyquaternion/blob/master/pyquaternion/quaternion.py

This is a snippet of the python code:

```
q = Quaternion(quaternion)
R = q.rotation_matrix
```

My code in C++ is this: where q_0 ... q_3 are the elements of the quaternion

```
FXMVECTOR v_quaternion= XMLoadFloat4(&XMFLOAT4(q_0, q_1, q_2, q_3))
viewMatrix = XMMatrixRotationQuaternion(v_quaternion);
```

I am not versed in python, but my understanding from the library is that the first element in a `pyquaternion` is the real number, and the other 3 are the `i`, `j`, and `k` values.

According to this document, `FXMVECTOR` struct is supposed to have member variables `X`,`Y`,`Z`, and `W`. But it doesn't because it's `typedef`ined as an `XMVECTOR` in DirectXmath.h and I do not know in which order I need to input quaternion elements in order to construct it.

I tested both
`FXMVECTOR v_quaternion= XMLoadFloat4(&XMFLOAT4(q_0, q_1, q_2, q_3))`
and
`FXMVECTOR v_quaternion= XMLoadFloat4(&XMFLOAT4(q_3, q_0, q_1, q_2))`

Needless to say, all my cameras were oriented in completely wrong locations.

So my 2 questions are:

1. What is the proper way to construct a quaternion from the {Real, I, J, K} representation in DirectX11
2. What is the correct way to convert that quaternion to a rotation matrix in DirectX

Thank you,

Comment: If you don't know the order use something like `vec = XMFLOAT4(), vec.W = q_0`

Comment: You are using the correct function. XMMatrixRotationQuaternion

Comment: according to this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/directxmath/ns-directxmath-xmfloat4 the order is (x,y,z,w)